# Eclipse C string does not overflow

Tags: c, eclipse, c-strings, buffer-overflow

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers, while I learn about C. In theory, overflow should take place somehow when I input bigger than the size of the string I assign. But it's just all good and I cannot see the desired trouble.

```
int main()
{
    char nameArr[15];
    printf("Type name: ");
    scanf("%s",nameArr);
    printf("You are %s.\n",nameArr);

    return(0);
}
```

I wanted to intentionally see the case of overflow, but I could not. For example, when the run, if I type Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff, it outputs properly without any overflow-related message in Eclipse. I don't know if it is a feature of C or that of Eclipse. Does anyone know why it's fine with exceeding size?

Comment: C doesn't provide bounds checking, that's up to you. When you overflow the buffer it is undefined behavior and one of the results of that is that it can appear to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @retiredninja has mentioned in a comment, overflowing a buffer causes undefined behaviour, so you can't expect anything to happen or not happen.

In saying that, to observe some simple buffer overflow, you can try this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char overflow[16];
    char nameArr[16];
    overflow[15] = '\0';
    nameArr[15] = '\0';
    printf("Type name: ");
    scanf("%s" ,nameArr);
    printf("You are %s.\n", nameArr);
    printf("overflow: %s\n", overflow);

    return(0);
}
```

When I compile this with

```
gcc -Wall -W main.c -o main -fno-stack-protector -O0
```

and run it, I see

```
$ ./main
Type name: 123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
You are 123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.
overflow: hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

which shows that the extra text is written into the memory that neighbours the intended variable. The order matters here: these variables live on the stack, which grows downwards through memory, so the memory 'after' a variable belongs to the variable that was declared before it.

Note that everything in my answer is implementation-dependent, so can not be expected to occur with all compilers, OSes, etc. This is especially true because we are talking about undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This example illustrates only too well why it's important to make use of the tools at your disposal, to trap common programming errors. An array overflow like this can go undetected for years, right up until somebody uses it as the basis for an exploit. It's easy to make mistakes of this kind -- they're usually not as obvious as the one in the OP -- and they don't necessarily cause a failure when testing.

Modern C compilers offer protection against situations where an array is written off the end of the stack. They can't make the code *work*, but they can signal a failure so the fault can be followed up. For example, if I build the OP's code with `gcc` using `-fstack-protector`, then even a small overrun causes an immediate failure:

```
Type name: 12345678987654321
You are 12345678987654321.
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

Used in combination with a debugger, the problem code is detected very quickly.

If your compiler doesn't offer these kinds of checks, get a better compiler ;)